# Forcing subsequent SLURM jobs to wait until first job is done?

Tags: parallel-processing, cluster-computing

I am running 1000 jobs on a cluster, using a sbatch job array. I've set up my code such that if the job array index is set to 0, precomputations are executed and saved to file; the jobs 1-999 then access these precomputations.

The precomputations in job 0 take much less time than any of jobs 1-999.

Instead of manually submitting job 0 with some time limit T1, waiting for it to finish, then submitting jobs 1-999 with a job array and time limit T2, I would like to submitting everything from the same .sh file and:

- force jobs 1-999 to start only when job 0 is done
- enforce job 0 has time limit T1, and jobs 1-999 have limit T2.

Is something along these lines possible?